# C# derived class initialization

Tags: c#, initialization, derived-class

My C# code scenario:

```
public class BaseClass 
{
       public int A;
       public float B;
       //a multitude of other fields
       public string Y;
};

public class DerivedClass:BaseClass {
       public string Z;
       public DerivedClass (BaseClass b) {
       //??
       }
}
```

I want to write this DerivedClass constructor without explicit memberwise copy. In C++, a default BaseClass constructor would do it for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ as per the scenario even `: base ()` is not required. That is called by default unless we need to call an overloaded one with params. OP needs to post the correct code, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking if there's an easy way to create a copy constructor in C#.

No, there is no way to do this without specifying the fields you want to copy in one of the constructor explicitly.

see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an easy way to write fully functional [copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor) in c#. So either you implement it in `BaseClass` manually or you can use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to automate it.

Last option would be to try to use [Automapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) which will have some limitations(but for provided code should work) in terms what it can handle - only public properties/fields will be mapped and implementation will look like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private static readonly IMapper _mapper;
    static BaseClass()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<BaseClass, BaseClass>());
        _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }
    public int A;
    public float B;
    //a multitude of other fields
    public string Y;
    public BaseClass(){}
    public BaseClass(BaseClass b)
    {
        _mapper.Map<BaseClass, BaseClass>(b,this);
    }
};

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Z;
    public DerivedClass(BaseClass b): base(b)
    {
    }
}
```